# When to use `actionListner` and `action`? And which one will gets executed first?

Tags: java, jsf

I am new to Java. I have following doubt.

When to use `ActionListener` and when `Action`? And which one gets executed first?

Can someone explain in simple steps?

Comment: @JunedAhsan What if everybody at this site would refer people to google?

Comment: Dublicatet you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `actionListener` and `action` in jsf, then `actionListener` gets executed first.

Comment: Not a comment to this answer really, but why did you add the tag `jsf`?

Comment: because I am sure actionlistener and action method order execution. and all the answers refer to JSF only.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think this is limited to JSF? What about Swing?

Comment: I don't know about swing, but I was sure about JSF.

Comment: That's allright then. JSF is indeed included but I was thinking to keep this question more general. Doesn't matter too much though, do as you like :)

Comment: Thats fine :) Even I could be wrong :) Good that you kept generalized.

Comment: @Joetjah As Swing's `Action` extends `ActionListener`, asking which gets called first wouldn't begin to make sense if the OP meant Swing. Ergo he didn't. Conflating two completely different things doesn't constitute keeping things general, it just constitutes introducing confusion.